# Backbone route to /

Tags: backbone.js, routes, coffeescript, url-routing

I have a Backbone Router:

```
class X.Routers.Main extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    '/': 'home'
    'pageb': 'actionb'
    'pagec': 'actionc'
```

Pages B and C work, but navigating to http://domain.ext/ results in a page reload instead of triggering the right route.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can either  set `"*path": "home"` as your last route which will make it a default route or set `""` (instead of `"/"`)as your first route (which means root directory)

Answer (score 4):

1. your base url path IS NOT "/", BUT ""  (empty string)
2. I usually add optional "/" at the end of each route configuration, just in case
3. I also usually add default action handler at the end of configuration

So my routes configuration would be like:

```
routes = {
    '': 'home',
    'pageb(/)': 'actionB', // so /pageb or /pageb/ will call the same function
    'pagec(/)': 'actionC', // so /pagec or /pagec/ will call the same function
    '*action': 'defaultAction' // you can use it to render 404, or call home function
}
```

Hope this help